# Cleaning your post title in php for insertion to database for SEO links

Tags: php, regex, seo

I'm currently learning PHP and learning trying to get a string from user inputted data and insert it into the database, to use as a link for post on the site.
I'm using regular expressions in a function to alter the string like so:

```
function clean_url($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/','-',strtolower($string)); // allows only characters from a-z and 0-9 and converts string to lower case
    $string = preg_replace('/-$/', '-', $string); // replace dash -
    $string = preg_replace('/--+/','',$string); // replaces double dashes with a single dash
    $string = preg_replace('/^-/', '', $string); // replace dash
    return $string;
}
```

I'd like to combine all the regular expressions to one meaningful regex. With these rules in mind

1. only characters from a-z and 0-9 are allowed i.e no characters aside - are allowed
2. replaces all the - and the beginning and ending of the string with nothing.
3. replace all the double dashes -- with a single dash.

Comment: It seems vague leaving all the various regex statements like that, I want to combine all the statements into one regex.

Comment: Read through through, there is.

Comment: @Xorifelse Sorry, I'm just blind apparently.

Comment: @Maverick How can one combine all these regexes, when the replacement value is different? And why not use `str_replace()`, feed an array of chars into that function and done. The only regex that is useful is the first one.

Comment: @Xorifelse the others seem meaningful to me as well. I wouldn't like double dashes in my string, neither will  a dash at the start and end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` accepts arrays as arguments, so one way to do it is:

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9-]+/','/-$/','/--+/','/^-/'),array('-','-','',''),strtolower($string));
```

Personally, I prefer your original function with each expression on its own as it makes the code more readable. I would also consider using `str_replace()` for the simple replacements

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want any `-` characters on the end of the beginning of the string you can use `trim()`.

For the double dash replacement you can use `str_replace()` and for the numeric and alpabethic characters you can use `preg_replace()`.

```
function clean_url($string) {
  return trim(str_replace('--', '-', preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/','-', strtolower($string))), '-');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trim() does not remove dashes at the end or beginning of the string. It removes only white spaces.

Comment: @Maverick Straight from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). `trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string`. I am feeding `-` as the second argument to `trim()`

Comment: trim doesn't remove dashes from my string.

Comment: Ok, didn't think of that. Well done. Was just using trim('--hi there---), cool tip.